# Error in executing query in JBDS (Teiid)

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, jboss-developer-studio, teiid

I am using JBDS 10.4 with WildFly 10,Teiid Designer 10. Successfully made a VDB by following the link: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SalesforceAsARESTServiceUsingDataVirtualization?_sscc=t

When running on browser getting notfound error (404).
Tried to execute VDB, then Database Development perspective opened and when executed the query, it starts and is not completing(not changing from 0%).
I am not getting any errors,but getting following warning
 :

```
[org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO6)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session +tJUxJdXtP8C. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347).
```

EDIT (error logs after OPTIMIZATION COMPLETE:PROCESSOR PLAN:) :

```
2017-09-09 09:31:44,173 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session HWYX7pgSwHa1. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,175 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session LopCxnhFRcHx. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,176 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session IYgbw2oe1pvT. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,178 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session Cm59XEg1MrlD. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,180 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session 9/F8cj7wPFXz. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,181 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session XPa5O+m/MYsS. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,182 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session omRcugzE9ky1. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,184 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1)  TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session sP1SduL77Vb2. Session may have already been terminated.' for session null.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,193 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session i1nbdnUCs369. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,194 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session jR9QR129cvj4. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,205 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session OTQr9BXiXZeL. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,207 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session t8rpRYgRD7XT. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:31:44,211 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session /vnJ1FMRlvXB. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,082 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session HWYX7pgSwHa1. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,083 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session LopCxnhFRcHx. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,087 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session IYgbw2oe1pvT. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,089 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session Cm59XEg1MrlD. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,094 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session 9/F8cj7wPFXz. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,096 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session XPa5O+m/MYsS. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,108 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session omRcugzE9ky1. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,111 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session sP1SduL77Vb2. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,126 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session i1nbdnUCs369. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,127 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session jR9QR129cvj4. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,129 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session OTQr9BXiXZeL. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,131 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session t8rpRYgRD7XT. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:33:44,132 WARN  [org.teiid.SECURITY] (NIO1) /Y9Sh40s5Ij9 TEIID40011 Processing exception 'TEIID40042 Invalid Session /vnJ1FMRlvXB. Session may have already been terminated.' for session /Y9Sh40s5Ij9.  Exception type org.teiid.client.security.InvalidSessionException thrown from org.teiid.services.SessionServiceImpl.getSessionInfo(SessionServiceImpl.java:347). Enable more detailed logging to see the entire stacktrace.
2017-09-09 09:35:13,349 INFO  [org.teiid.PLANNER] (Worker8_QueryProcessorQueue40) e8o2iiRgWK4H
```

Comment: Can you post what are errors in server.log?

Comment: Edited the question with logs and version of TeiidDesigner @RameshReddy

Answer (score 0):

I think in the database perspective you are using an old connection to the VDB, and there has been another deployment of the VDB. When a new VDB gets deployed any old sessions are terminated on the server side. If you kill that connection and remake a new connection it should work.

Comment: You would have to list me steps you have taken for me to answer why the same error then.

Comment: Downloaded and install JBDS 10.4 ,

Merged bin,standalone,docs,module of wildfly server with it. ,

Installed Teiid Designer . ,

Added module.xml and teiid-jdbc.jar file. ,

Create VDB. ,

In Standalone-teiid.xml change driver from h2 to teiid. ,

Deployed the VDB .

Comment: See this for installation of Teiid and Teiid Designer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46244216/1772470

Comment: I followed the same documentation for installation. @RameshReddy

Comment: problem solved.                                              https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276059?start=15&tstart=0