# Install Teiid with jboss

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7, teiid

I have downloaded jboss EAP 7 and installed Teiid Designer 10.4  in it.
I don't know how to install Teiid.

What are the zip files I need to download from Teiid.

How can I install them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Teiid go to [downloads](http://teiid.jboss.org/downloads/) section and
download "9.3.3 With WildFly/Console" link or whatever is latest. The follow directions here for installation https://teiid.gitbooks.io/documents/content/admin/Installation_Guide.html

For Teiid Designer goto http://teiiddesigner.jboss.org/designer_summary/downloads, the directions for different ways to install are on that page.

Note Teiid and Teiid Designer are two different downloads. Teiid is a runtime server and Teiid Designer is Eclipse-based Tool. There are plenty of [getting started materials](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/teiidexamples/Quick+Starts) on the [teiid web site](http://teiid.org) check it out.

Comment: It worked.Added jar file of Teiid and module.mxl.

I am using a ddl file as source ,what should be the value for translator.

Comment: It worked.
But when executing VDB and running query, getting an error like

Caused by : org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException: Remote org.teiid.api.execution.query.QuertParserException:TEIID31100 Parsing error.

I already added JDBC driver.

Comment: Check your SQL statement you are executing, typically parsing error means your SQL statement is wrong